# Spring WebSockets and SockJS - can't make fallback options work

Tags: spring, websocket, sockjs

I'm looking at Spring's new WebSockets/SockJS feature and trying to force a fallback to one of the non-WebSocket transports. Can't make it work. Below are the details.

Here's my configuration (there's only one configuration class):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Config implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(dummyHandler(), "/hello").withSockJS();
    }

    @Bean
    public DummyServerWebSocketHandler dummyHandler() {
        return new DummyServerWebSocketHandler();
    }
}
```

The `DummyServerWebSocketHandler` is quite trivial: it's an echo service with some logging. Then, my test is:

1. Connect using `SockJS` client
2. Send a message
3. Receive a message back

This scenario works fine as long as I use `WebSocketTransport`:

```
SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(Arrays.<Transport>asList(
    new WebSocketTransport(new StandardWebSocketClient())));

WebSocketConnectionManager webSocketConnectionManager = new WebSocketConnectionManager(
    sockJsClient,
    new DummyClientWebSocketHandler(messageExchanger),
    "ws://localhost:8080/hello");
webSocketConnectionManager.start();
```

The log is:

```
o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketConnectionManager     : Connecting to WebSocket at ws://localhost:8080/hello
me.loki2302.DummyServerWebSocketHandler  : /127.0.0.1:50847 connected
tHandlerTest$DummyClientWebSocketHandler : connected to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketConnectionManager     : Successfully connected
me.loki2302.DummyServerWebSocketHandler  : /127.0.0.1:50847 says: loki2302
tHandlerTest$DummyClientWebSocketHandler : localhost/127.0.0.1:8080 says: hello loki2302!
me.loki2302.DummyServerWebSocketHandler  : /127.0.0.1:50847 disconnected
tHandlerTest$DummyClientWebSocketHandler : localhost/127.0.0.1:8080 disconnected
```

Then I change `sockJsClient` construction to:

```
SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(Arrays.<Transport>asList(
    new RestTemplateXhrTransport()));
```

That's the only change. The log is:

```
o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketConnectionManager     : Connecting to WebSocket at ws://localhost:8080/hello
me.loki2302.DummyServerWebSocketHandler  : /127.0.0.1:50919 connected
tHandlerTest$DummyClientWebSocketHandler : connected to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
s.w.s.s.t.h.XhrReceivingTransportHandler : Failed to read message
```

The exception thrown is:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('%' (code 37)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')

And here's a stacktrace:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('%' (code 37)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@ef6a283; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1419)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:508)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:437)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2363)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:794)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:690)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3090)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3036)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2192)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.frame.Jackson2SockJsMessageCodec.decodeInputStream(Jackson2SockJsMessageCodec.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.XhrReceivingTransportHandler.readMessages(XhrReceivingTransportHandler.java:41)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.AbstractHttpReceivingTransportHandler.handleRequestInternal(AbstractHttpReceivingTransportHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.AbstractHttpReceivingTransportHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHttpReceivingTransportHandler.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.TransportHandlingSockJsService.handleTransportRequest(TransportHandlingSockJsService.java:256)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.AbstractSockJsService.handleRequest(AbstractSockJsService.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(SockJsHttpRequestHandler.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

First, I'm not sure if it's expected to work like this at all. Then, if it should work, is there anything I'm missing?

I'm using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:1.2.0.M1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some explorations, I've discovered that message received by server looks like `%5B%22loki2302%22%5D=`, which is URI-encoded `["loki2302"]=`.

The issue disappeared once I replaced `RestTemplate`'s default `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` with `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`, the request that server receives is now just `["loki2302"]`.

Comment: How exactly did you do this? I cannot find any reference to this in your question code.

Comment: @Wouter: use constructor `public RestTemplate(ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory)` to specify the request factory (see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#RestTemplate-org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory-)